# Conteúdo fora da DIV

Tags: css, posicionamento

Sou iniciante na area e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.
Não sei o que eu faço para deixar o conteúdo dentro da div.
Veja que na aba 'skills' estão saindo para fora da div .row. E no responsivo também está!
Acredito que tenha algo a ver com as positions, mas não estou conseguindo acertar.

```css
section {
    padding: 1.5rem 7%;
    margin: 6rem 0;
}

.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap: 1.5rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

.about-content, .image {
    flex: 1 1 50rem;
}

.row .image img {
    width: 100%;
}

.row .tab-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none; 
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.row .tab-wrapper input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.row .tab-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
    background-color: var(--skin-color);
    color: var(--bg-color)
}

.row .tab-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .tab-content {
    display: block;
}

.row .tab-wrapper li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.row .tab-wrapper label {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #717273;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.row .tab-wrapper .tab-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 45px; 
    display: none;
    border-top: 3px solid var(--skin-color);
}

.row .tab-wrapper .tab-content p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: justify;
    color: var(--primary-color);
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .experience {
    color: var(--skin-color); 
}

.about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .education {
    margin-top: 3.5rem; 
    font-size: 1.5rem;  
}


.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .btn-cv {
    padding: 1rem 6rem;
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item h3 {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item .progress {
    background-color: #7172736b;
    height: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item .progress-in {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--skin-color);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .tab-wrapper {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .tab-wrapper li {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
    }

    .tab-wrapper label {
        padding: 15px 11px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tab-wrapper .tab-content {
        top: 200px;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="image">
                <img src="https://ec-aminhota.pt/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/perfil-sem-foto-220615.png" alt="">
            </div>
    
            <div class="about-content">
                <ul class="tab-wrapper">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab" checked>
                        <label for="tab-1">SOBRE</label> 
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias dolor fugiat laudantium consequuntur, velit neque placeat deleniti ullam ratione tempora perferendis asperiores, cumque harum veritatis? Quam totam recusandae consequatur impedit?
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-cv">Baixar CV</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab">
                        <label for="tab-2">SKILLS</label> 
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>HTML5</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 95%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>CSS3</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 86%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>SASS/SCSS</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 86%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>JAVASCRIPT</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 55%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>JQUERY</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 55%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>DESIGN RESPONSIVO/MEDIA QUERIES</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 85%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>UX</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 83%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>OUTRO</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 83%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>OUTRO</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 83%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>OUTRO</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 83%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-item">
                                <h3>OUTRO</h3>
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-in" style="width: 83%;"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab">
                        <label for="tab-3">EXPERIÊNCIAS</label> 
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="experience professional">
                                <h3>PROFISSIONAL</h3>
                                <p>Ano - Função <br>
                                <span>Nome da Empresa</span></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="experience education">
                                <h3>ACADÊMICA</h3>
                                <p>Ano - NOME DO CURSO <br><span>NOME DA UNIVERSIDADE</span></p>
                                <p>Ano - NOME DO CURSO <br> <span>NOME DA UNIVERSIDADE</span></p>
                            </div>                            
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Faltou limitar a área das divs e usar um overflow-scroll

```
section {
    padding: 1.5rem 7%;
    margin: 6rem 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
    gap: 1.5rem;
    border: 0.1rem solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.about-content,
.image {
    flex: 1 1 50rem;
}

.row .image img {
    width: 100%;
}

.row .tab-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.row .tab-wrapper input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.row .tab-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked~label {
    background-color: var(--skin-color);
    color: var(--bg-color)
}

.row .tab-wrapper input[type="radio"]:checked~.tab-content {
    display: block;
}

.row .tab-wrapper li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.row .tab-wrapper label {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #717273;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.row .tab-wrapper .tab-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 45px;
    display: none;
    border-top: 3px solid var(--skin-color);
}
.row .tab-wrapper .tab-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
.row .tab-wrapper .tab-content p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-align: justify;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 350px;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .experience {
    color: var(--skin-color);
}

.about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .education {
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}


.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .btn-cv {
    padding: 1rem 6rem;
    margin-top: 4rem;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item h3 {
    color: var(--primary-color);
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item .progress {
    background-color: #7172736b;
    height: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.row .about-content .tab-wrapper .tab-content .skill-item .progress-in {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--skin-color);
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .tab-wrapper {
        width: 80%;
    }

    .tab-wrapper li {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 18px;
    }

    .tab-wrapper label {
        padding: 15px 11px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tab-wrapper .tab-content {
        top: 200px;
    }

}
```